# What would a negative margin on all four sides do in CSS?

Tags: html, css, margin

If I wrote this:

```
#element {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

By general rule, it would move the element upwards by 50 pixels.

Recently, I accidentally used this bit of code instead:

```
.elements {
  margin: -50px;
}
```

So I had these `<div>` tags, one beneath the other, and by writing `margin: -50px;` they all somehow got closer together.

But thinking in retrospect, I don't really see how this worked. The size of the elements didn't change (as far as I know, as they contained child elements, and the child elements were closer together as well), and they didn't seem to zoom in size or anything.

I did some research online, but all I could find was for negative margins on one or two sides at most.

Is there an explanation to this? What actually happens? Maybe it's because I'm using Google Chrome, and maybe nothing happens in other browsers?

Comment: the margin is removed from all sides equally, making the margin in between div's smaller. really that simple.

Comment: @r3wt yes, but wouldn't that expand the elements? in my case, that doesn't happen.

Comment: no it wouldn't expand the elements unless they have % based width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tha margin is not added to the *appearance* of the element but rather to its *bounds*, so basically your element looks e.g. `200x200` but its bounds are equal to that of an element of `100x100` since you substract `50px` from every side. Try it for yourself:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/arielnmz/Lnbe9/1/).

HTML:

```
<div class="e1"><div></div></div>
<div class="e2"><div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 100px;
}
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: -50px;
}

.e1 {
    background: red;
}

.e2 {
    background: yellow;
}

.e1>div, .e2>div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

I've added a padding to the body to make the elements be pushed down so you can see the overlap they cause. Updated so you can see the bounds of the squares that *result*.